# django-taggit deep relationship query

Tags: django, django-orm, django-taggit

I'm using django-taggit and I came upon a problem when trying to filter across relationships.

Having the following models:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
     tags = TaggableManager()


class Gig(models.Model):
    artist = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
```

What I would like to achieve is the get all gigs who's artist(s) have a specific tag.

I thought this would be easy and eagerly wrote:

```
Gig.objects.filter(artist__tags__name__in=["rock"])
```

Which gave me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/jonas/.virtualenvs/wsw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line  141, in filter
return self.get_query_set().filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jonas/.virtualenvs/wsw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 550, in filter
  return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jonas/.virtualenvs/wsw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 568, in _filter_or_exclude
clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/home/jonas/.virtualenvs/wsw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1172, in add_q
can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
File "/home/jonas/.virtualenvs/wsw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1139, in add_filter
process_extras=False)
File "/home/jonas/.virtualenvs/wsw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1060, in add_filter
negate=negate, process_extras=process_extras)
File "/home/jonas/.virtualenvs/wsw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1238, in setup_joins
"Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names)))
 FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'tagged_items' into field. Choices are: artist, date, id, location, url
```

Comment: I see that you posted this a few months ago. Did you get it solved?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I never got it solved. I just switched to django-tagging which made such kind of behavior possible. But I have to warn you about it's API structure compared to django-taggit. Still it has some good elaborate documentation.

Comment: I have the same issue, as did another. More details on this django-taggit issue thread: https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/issues/84#issuecomment-3554357

Comment: I wish I could remember why I decided to use taggit instead of django-tagging now...! :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by commenting out **TaggableManager.extra_filters()** in *manage.py*.

Take it with a grain of salt, because I have no idea what I may have broken by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Getting all Gigs for who's Artist's have a specific tag.

```
artists = Artist.objects.filter(tags__name__in=["rock"])
gigs = Gig.objects.filter(artist__in=artists)
```